# Force IE8 to use Browser compatibility view

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have a page using the mixitup jquery script.
It works perfectly in Chrome, Opera and IE11.

But I need it to work in IE8 too.

I have the script working in IE8, just without the fancy animations, which is fine.

Except, it only works in IE8 when I set the browser compatibility view to 'Internet Explorer 8 Compatibility View'.

In the screenshot below, it shows different version, but you can see what option I mean, the second one rather than the first one.

[image: I need 'Internet Explorer 8 Compatibility View' not 'Internet Explorer 8']

I have tried entering the following meta to the top of page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
```

and also:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >
```

But both those just seem to force the 'Internet Explorer 8', the equivalent to the top options in the screenshot... not the second one, which I need.

Can that be done?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then may be below explanation will help you.

Using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content=" _______  " />`

- The Standard User Agent modes (the non-emulate ones) ignore `<!DOCTYPE>` directives in your page and render based on the standards supported by that version of IE (e.g., `IE=8` will better obey table border spacing and some pseudo selectors than `IE=7`).
- Whereas, the Emulate modes tell IE to follow any `<!DOCTYPE>` directives in your page, rendering standards mode based the version you choose and quirks mode based on `IE=5`
- Possible values for the content attribute are:
  `content="IE=5"`

  `content="IE=7"`

  `content="IE=EmulateIE7"`

  `content="IE=8"`

  `content="IE=EmulateIE8"`

  `content="IE=9"`

  `content="IE=EmulateIE9"`

  `content="IE=edge"`

If meta tag solution wasn't working for you then set it

```
header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1');
```